# What would be helpful for newbies to know before getting started?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've seen several posts sending newbies to the [Tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials), but are there **skills, concepts, or useful tidbits** that would be useful for our new friends (and help to minimize potential frustration for them and the community.)

I would like to generate a wiki post from the top responses, so if some of these themes have been asked/answered here or elsewhere, the links to that content could be included as comments to the provided answer.

Justification for any answer is not needed, let the upvotes work for us.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42730/what-would-be-helpful-for-newbies-to-know-before-getting-started?/) by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2022 on 2012-08-31

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2012-08-31**:
An examples could include "A basic understanding of networking"...

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2012-09-01**:
environment variables?

**Comment by [Aakashp](https://answers.ros.org/users/57188/aakashp/) on 2020-10-29**:
@SL Remy have you generated a wiki post ? If yes, please share the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First I'll try to elaborate a bit on the already mentioned points:

1. Basic Linux and especially Ubuntu

- Getting used to using the windows and workspaces relevant shortcuts (in Unity, hold SUPER/WINDOWS)
- Knowing what apt-get does and how it works
- Knowing how to set up ssh connections using keys

2. Using the terminal

- Getting familiar with TAB completion and history
- Know the basic shortcuts CTRL+C, CTRL+ALT+T, CTRL+SHIFT+T, CTRL+(+|-|0)

What also helped me:

1. Having a basic knowledge of threads and their hazards (especially relevant for C++)
2. Getting familiar with version control systems and their underlying concepts

- git, subversion and mercurial are all used in ROS repositories
  - Focus on one and use it for your projects (git works best for me)

---

Originally posted by [pgorczak](https://answers.ros.org/users/3055/pgorczak/) with karma: 446 on 2012-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2012-09-04**:
http://linuxcommand.org/

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2012-09-04**:
http://www.linux.org/tutorial/view/beginners-level-course

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The most obvious things for me would be

1. a basic understanding of linux and how to use the command line.
2. Familiar with programming in either C++ or Python.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-08-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3